# I'm not sure if this is a valid Ubuntu bug to file

Tags: installation, keyboard, dvorak

I was in the process of filing an bug on Launchpad, but I had second thoughts because there were so many threatening warnings of the effect, "Don't file a bug report unless you're sure it's a bug, and you should really provide a package name".

The problem I have, and I've had it for years, is the following:

When I'm installing Ubuntu, it asks me to type in my location *before* it asks me what my keyboard layout is. Using a QWERTY keyboard with the buttons popped off and in the Dvorak order, this is annoying, because it is assumes I am using a QWERTY keyboard, and so I have to guess at where all the QWERTY keys are to spell my city's name. It seems like it would make more sense to switch the order of these two questions.

(I'll be the first person to admit that this is a very minor problem that has probably wasted less than 2 minutes of my life in total -- but it's the principle of the thing :p)

So my question is: is this order there for a particular reason, and if it isn't, is it appropriate to file it as a bug, and under which package name?

Comment: I enjoy this question. What a clever idea, rather than purchasing a dvorak keyboard, you just change the software layout and move the buttons around.

Comment: @ThomasBoxley You can even do it on most laptops if you're brave enough. On some desktop keyboards, however, the tilt of the keys on each of the three keyboard rows is slightly different, which will make the rearrangement look weird.

Comment: The drawback is, if you ever need to type Qwerty (in the bios, the boot loader, etc) it's *really confusing*: no keycaps _and_ your fingers are trained to Dvorak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's a reasonable bug to file.

To find the right place to file it, you can Google for something like `site:launchpad.net ubuntu installer`.  I think [Ubiquity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity) would be a reasonable place to start - people can always move it if it's not exactly right.

It's also worth searching the web for some keywords around the symptoms you're experiencing eg `ubuntu installer keyboard layout`, to see if it's already known.

You might read http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

However, I also use Dvorak, and I've never noticed a problem there.  Maybe I just always use the mouse or cursor keys to choose my location?  I tend to install from the Alternate disk and I know there you can choose the keymap using the cursor keys from the boot loader screen.

There's a bit of a chicken and egg thing here, in that the installer wants to use your location to suggest the most likely keyboard layout.  Asking you for the layout first won't help much in guessing a location.